# NSMutableDictionary KVO

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

I'm trying to observe changes in dictionary using KVO.

Example:

```
dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[dictionary setObject:@"test1" forKey:@"key1"];
[dictionary setObject:@"test2" forKey:@"key2"];    
[dictionary setObject:@"test3" forKey:@"key1"];
```

I'd love to be able to hook an observer for whenever a value is added to the dictionary. removed, or replaced (ie in the above cases, whenever any of the setObject methods are called)

So in conclusion:
I want a function to have

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

called when I ADD a any new entry to a dictionary, or Remove any entry, or REPLACE any entry.

NOT: I do NOT want to have to specify which keys I'm observing for. (eg observe only when @"key1" is added) as this solution doesn't scale.

Comment: What happens if you observe the key `@"@count"` on the dictionary?

Comment: No. Didn't work. If I replace @"@count" with @"key2" it works but that's not a univeral solution.

Answer (score 8):

Subclassing NSMutableDictionary is a bit annoying, due to the fact that NSDictionary and its friends are class clusters.   It's certainly doable, and if you have to pass the object itself to another set of classes, then you may want to do exactly that.   Otherwise, it might be easier to create a composite class which has the same basic API and uses NSMutableDictionary object internally for storage.   There's a pretty good write-up as CocoaWithLove.com, [Ordered Dictionary Subclassing](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html), which goes into doing this.

However, that doesn't completely solve your problem.    What I would suggest is that you begin with a subclass or decorator class such as the one above, then add support explicitly for `-(NSArray*)allKeys`, which is a standard accessor in `NSDictionary` itself.   Then, you can add support to pass along change messages for allKeys, which will make it observable.

This can be done by adding the following code around the `-setObject:forKey:` and `-removeObjectForKey:` methods.

```
- (void)setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id)aKey
{
    BOOL addKey=NO;
    if (![dictionary objectForKey: aKey]) {
        addKey=YES;
        [self willChangeValueForKey: @"allKeys"];   
    }
    [dictionary setObject:anObject forKey:aKey];
    if (addKey)
        [self didChangeValueForKey: @"allKeys"];
}

- (void)removeObjectForKey:(id)aKey
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey: @"allKeys"];
    [dictionary removeObjectForKey:aKey];
    [self didChangeValueForKey: @"allKeys"];
}
```

What is being done here is that we're adding explicit KVO notification to the class when the dictionary's keys are changed to mark a change in the array.

This will take care of adds and removes.   If you want changes to be notified on the same basis, you can remove the if statements, and just have allKeys notify on either set or remove, like this:

```
- (void)setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id)aKey
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey: @"allKeys"];   
    [dictionary setObject:anObject forKey:aKey];
    [self didChangeValueForKey: @"allKeys"];
}
```

Then, in your code, you put in a single observer for the key @"allKeys" on this object and you'll be receiving notifications whenever an item changes.

Comment: I agree with this conclusion. Thanks gaige. I'm going to implement this.

Comment: If it works, don't forget to up vote the answers you found helpful and mark as answered the one that provided your solution.

Comment: When the NSMutableDictionary grows in size, will those methods not be called again for each key??

Comment: "Grows in size" is an interesting choice of description.   I show two variants in my code, one for noting the addition and removal of keys in the dictionary, and the other showing any time that changes are made to the dictionary (basically the removal of the `if` statement in the `setObject:forKey:` method).

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem by adding an observer to the mutable dictionary "translator" in this way:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"translator.@count" options:0 context:NULL];
```

My app manages the data in a the classical way, using a tableview, a controller and the dictionary as KVO property "translator".
The dictionary is bound to a NSDictionaryController in my XIB, and a tableview content is bound to the controller.

This are the connections of the tableview:

[image]

Now, in any of the following cases I catch the change :

- adding a key-value pair
- removing a key-value pair
- changing a key
- changing a value

Remark: unfortunately, this approach does not work with NSMutableArrays.
Changes are not recognized

Answer (score 0):

Can't you subclass NSMutableDictionary and override the various setters?  For instance, overriding setObject:forKey: by calling super, then immediately calling addObserver...

You can also write a wrapper for NSMutableDictionary where you force yourself to use custom setters to manipulate the underlying NSMutableDictionary.

Maybe I need more context to any of your limitations or scalability intents.

Comment: It's illegal to override NSMutableDictionary (much to my surprise). Calling [super SetObject: forKey:] causes an exception saying something about an abstract class. I'm leaning towards composition and reimplementing all the functions a dictionary can provide (PITA and none polymorphic). The scalability issue was in referance to the fact that you can only observe changes to "key1" in the dictionary and not "*" changes to the dictionary. So I can't notify an observer if a new key is added to the dictionary.

Comment: Interesting indeed.  So far I think the decorator class might be the best option.  You don't have to reimplement all the methods though. You could just have the dictionary as a member and call [myObject.dictionary nsdictionarymethod] for any non-kvo operations  And just re-implement add, set, remove methods.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be helpful

```
- (void)addObserver:(id)observer {
    for (id key in grid)
        [self addObserver:observer
               forKeyPath:[key description]
                  options:0
                  context:key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think another way to do this is using the below override, incase you are observing NSMutableDictionary "allRecentCurrencyData" whose values are dependent on recentBrazilReals, recentEuEuro, recentUkPounds, recentJapanYen, the observer will get called, but the drawback is you need to know the keys before hand to do this.

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSSet *keyPaths = [super keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:key];

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"allRecentCurrencyData"]) {
       NSArray *affectingKeys = @[@"recentBrazilReals", @"recentEuEuro",@"recentUkPounds",@"recentJapanYen"];
      keyPaths = [keyPaths setByAddingObjectsFromArray:affectingKeys];
    }
    return keyPaths;
}
```