# Detect any changes in NSMutableDictionary/NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing

I am building an app that exposes a dictionary to a WebView with JavaScriptCore. It's options for the content of the page. It is a dictionary with multiple (and differing) keys and the values can also be dictionaries or array (in addition to strings, etc).

With non-dictionary values it's straight forward, simply overriding the setter, however, that isn't appropriate here. When the value changes I need to then save it, but I am having trouble with nested values.

I have looked in to KVO, however, this only allows a single key. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611965/nsmutabledictionary-kvo) seems promising, but as I am using JavaScriptCore to 'convert' my dictionary to a JavaScript object I may need to keep an instance of NSDictionary. Changing all the child dictionaries and arrays would be required too which is far from ideal.

I could try looping over each key and observing each on and child keys, but probably won't work with new keys.

If there is a method in the (horrendously documented) JavaScriptCore which might help that would be excellent too.

Comment: You could make the dictionary property immutable.  It's then pretty obvious when it changes!  Override the setter like the rest.

Comment: @stevesliva Won't that just crash it? I'm not exactly sure what you mean really.